# Running several spark jobs concurrently from driver

Tags: apache-spark

Imagine that we have 3 customers and we want do some same work for each of them in parallel.

```
def doSparkJob(customerId: String) = {
  spark
    .read.json(s"$customerId/file.json")
    .map(...)
    .reduceByKey(...)
    .write
    .partitionBy("id")
    .parquet("output/")
}
```

We do it concurrently like this (from spark driver):

```
val jobs: Future[(Unit, Unit, Unit)] = for {
  f1 <- Future { doSparkJob("customer1") }
  f2 <- Future { doSparkJob("customer1") }
  f3 <- Future { doSparkJob("customer1") }
} yield (f1, f2, f3)

Await.ready(jobs, 5.hours)
```

Do I understand correctly that this is bad approach? Many spark job will push out context of each other from executors and there will be many spilling data to disc appears. How spark will be manage execute task from parallel jobs? How shuffle appears when we have 3 concurrent job from one driver and only 3 executors with one core.

I guess, a good approach should looks like this:
We read all data together for all customers groupByKey by customer and do what we want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I understand correctly that this is bad approach?

Not necessarily. A lot depends on the context and Spark implements it's own set of `AsyncRDDActions` to address scenarios like this one (though there is no `Dataset` equivalent).

In the simplest scenario, with static allocation, it is quite likely that Spark will just schedule all jobs sequentially, due to lack of resources. Unless configured otherwise, this is the most probable outcome with the described configuration. Please keep in mind that Spark can use in-application scheduling with FAIR scheduler to share limited resources between multiple concurrent jobs. See [Scheduling Within an Application](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#scheduling-within-an-application).

If amount of resources is sufficient to start multiple jobs at the same, there can be competition between individual jobs, especially for IO and memory intensive jobs. If all jobs use the same of resources (especially databases) it is possible that Spark will cause throttling and subsequent failures or timeouts. A less severe effect of running multiple jobs can be increased cache eviction.

Overall there multiple factors to consider when you choose between sequential and concurrent execution including, but not limited to, available resource (Spark cluster and external services), choice of the API (RDD tend to be more greedy than SQL, therefore requires some low level management) and choice of operators. Even if jobs are sequentially you may still decide to use asynchronous to improve driver utilization and reduce latency. This is particularly useful with Spark SQL and complex execution plans (common bottleneck in Spark SQL). This way Spark can crunch new execution plans, while other jobs are executed.