# Order of execution and need of caching

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, bigdata

Let's consider such a snippet of python pseudo-code, using spark.

```
    rdd1 = sc.textFile("...")
    rdd2 = rdd1.map().groupBy().filter()
    importantValue = rdd2.count()
    rdd3 = rdd1.map(lambda x : x / importantValue)
```

In `DAG` of spark's tasks, there are two branches, after creating `rdd1`. Both branches use `rdd1`, but the second one (computing `rdd3`) uses also  aggregated value from `rdd2` (`importantValue`). I assume that `DAG` looks something like this:
[image]
Am I right? If yes, can we assume that `rdd1` used in computing `rdd3` is still handled in memory? Or we have to cache `rdd1` in order to prevent repeated loading of that?

More generally, if `DAG` looks like this:
[image]
can we assume that both branches  are computed pararelly and use the same copy of `rdd1`? Or Spark driver will compute these branches one after another, because these are two different stages? I know that before execution spark driver is splitting `DAG` into stages and more detailed logical parts - `tasks`. Tasks within one stage can computed in pararell, because there is no shuffle stage within, but what about two pararell branches as in the image? I know all intuition behing rdd abstraction (lazy evaluetion etc.) but that doesn't make things easier for me to understand. Please give me any advices.

Answer (score 1):

> I assume that DAG looks something like this: Am I right?

Yes.

> If yes, can we assume that rdd1 used in computing rdd3 is still handled in memory?

No. Spark utilizes lazy evaluation to process data. This means that nothing is computed until it is needed. And nothing will be stored unless there is an explicit statement to do so.

> Or we have to cache rdd1 in order to prevent repeated loading of that?

Exactly, you would need to cache rdd1 to prevent the text file from being read twice.

> More generally, if DAG looks like this: can we assume that both branches are computed pararelly and use the same copy of rdd1? Or Spark driver will compute these branches one after another, because these are two different stages?

The two branches will not be processed in parallel as they have separate lineages. In general, no data is processed until an action is taken. Whenever a result is needed (read, an action is called for), the data processing for all the proceeding transformations and the current action in a given lineage will occur. After that, no data will exist in memory unless `cache` was called.

See this [deck](https://training.databricks.com/visualapi.pdf) for an explanation of transformations vs actions

Answer (score 1):

> Can we assume that rdd1 used in computing rdd3 is still handled in memory? Or we have to cache rdd1 in order to prevent repeated loading of that?

`rdd1` is not cached. To cache it, you need to explicitly cache it and make sure that the RDD returned by `.cache()` is stored in the variable used to create `rdd2`:

```
rdd1 = sc.textFile("...").cache()
rdd2 = rdd1.map().groupBy().filter()
```

If this were to be added to your diagram, there would be another RDD between `rdd1` and `rdd2`.

> Can we assume that both branches are computed pararelly and use the same copy of rdd1? Or Spark driver will compute these branches one after another, because these are two different stages?

What determines whether jobs run in parallel is not the (branches in) lineage, it's the job requests themselves. Suppose you ran:

```
rdd4.count()
rdd5.count()
```

This would execute `rdd1`->`rdd2`->`rdd4` then count, **then** `rdd1`->`rdd3`->`rdd5`. This computation will be sequential.

To run these two graphs in parallel, then jobs must be submitted in parallel (asynchronous calls). There are many questions addressing this topic. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712420/how-to-run-concurrent-jobsactions-in-apache-spark-using-single-spark-context) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46252165/runnig-several-spark-jobs-concurrently-from-driver).

Comment: Thanks for replay. Would be so nice to look at few more issues? 1. Do you think it's good intuition to think about RDD more as recipe to reach result, rather than data structure? 2. By another RDD between `rdd1` and `rdd2` you mean `cached-rdd1`? 3. What if we have big amount of memory in our cluster and after computing `rdd1`->`rdd2`->`rdd4`, `rdd1` is still in  memory. I mean it wasn't vanished or overwritten by another data. Does spark take advatange of such a situation or spark just check some kind of flag `isCached` and perform only based on that information, even if data is availaible.

Comment: @Michocio 1. I think that's a good way to look at it. It fits the functional style used in the model and goes well with the declarative approach (It's more "I want a, I want b,..." rather than "do a like this, then from that do b like that"). 2. Correct 3. You need to cache/persist RDDs explicitly, and I think this was a good design decision (too many rdds get created, most internally). Check https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence for info on rdd caching.